# Why can't I use negative indexing for this pandas dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

My dataframe is like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
'Column A': [1, np.nan, 7],
'Column B': [np.nan, 2, 3],
'Column C': [np.nan, 2, np.nan]
})
```

I can use this index below and get the desired outcome 7.

```
a["Column A"][2]
```

However, when I want to find the last one, this one below doesn't work. What could be the reason for that?

```
a["Column A"][-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because indexing is not positional but by label. For positional indexing use `iloc`:

```
a["Column A"].iloc[-1]
```

Alternatively, if you have unique indices, you can also use:

```
a.loc[a.index[-1], 'Column A']
```

Which also allows you to assign a value.

Comment: Note that, if you want to set a value and have unique indices, you should better do: `a[a.index[-1], "Column A"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you use square brackets or `loc` you use this index:

```
    ||
   \  /
    \/
       Column A  Column B  Column C
    0       1.0       NaN       NaN
    1       NaN       2.0       2.0
    2       7.0       3.0       NaN
```

Do you see -1 somewhere?